# Initializing a userform with preset values?

Tags: vba, excel, radio-button, initialization, userform

Working in VBA for excel 2010. This is my first time working with VBA and userforms. Right now I have a barebones userform "UserForm1" trying to sort this issue out. It consists of two radio buttons "OptionButton1" and "OptionButton2" belonging to GroupName "WK" and two textboxes "TextBox1" and "TextBox2".

When I run the userform, I want "OptionButton1" to be selected and the subsequent if/then statements to be run. However, right now I cannot get it to do this. My code:

```
Public Sub UserForm1_Initialize()
UserForm1.Show
Me.OptionButton1.Value = False
Me.OptionButton1.Value = True
MsgBox ("dia locked")
Me.TextBox1.Value = "blah"
End Sub

Public Sub UserForm1_Activate()

End Sub

Public Sub OptionButton1_Click()

If Me.OptionButton1.Value = True Then
MsgBox ("dia locked")
Me.TextBox1.Value = "blah"
End If

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

End Sub
```

When I run the form, nothing happens and "OptionButton1" is false. If I click it, the message box displays and the textbox displays the text. It just won't do it on startup. I have tried going into the optionbutton properties and setting 'value' to true, which makes it true on startup, **but the messagebox still doesn't display and the textbox is blank** until I click it.

...please help. Thank you.

Comment: after `Me.OptionButton1.Value = True` line in class initialize just put in a call to your click sub - i.e. `OptionButton1_Click`. That's it ;)

Comment: Thanks Cor_Blimey! That works splendidly. I swear this language has more possible commands than any other.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

I suddenly found the dropdowns. Apparently I should have put Userform_Initialize() instead of UserForm1_Initialize(), and instead of OptionButton1_Click() I put the code into OptionButton1_Change() which ran the subsequent initialization sequence.

You guys/gals are awesomesauce. I have learned everything from reading your threads. Thank you!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj692790%28v=office.15%29.aspx has a load of helpful topics / language reference